# How can I change my login page without losing users' saved passwords?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, caching, browser, passwords

I've got an web application with a login page- `login.aspx`, which has two textboxes- username and password.

Users have been using it for years, and many of them have used the browser's facility to store their password, so they don't have to keep re-typing it.

I've now redesigned the login page, and need it to replace the old one.

The trouble is that I don't want users' saved passwords to be lost. Some of them (sigh!) can't actually remember their passwords, and rely on the browser filling it in for them. Now, I realise that these users are stupid and that it seems pretty reasonable for them to remember one password. But my client is adamant that they won't and thinks they'll go elsewhere if they can't log in straight away.

So how can I make sure old passwords are retained? What do browsers use to determine whether passwords should apply to a particular field?

N.B. I should mention that I am primarily interested in Internet Explorer, since that is what the majority of our users use.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:-** 
***To get User name :*** From your old login page, get the user name. 
***To get password :*** First of all, you should read your browser password database file. Different browsers use different locations to store the password file. Also, password files will be in encrypted format. Decrypt the password file and get the password.

**Step 2:-** 
**To remember the user again in that system:-**
In your new login page, put the user name in user name field and put the password(you have retrived) in password field. 
Now write a code to create a cookie file. 
It will remember you whenever you login from that system. 
I hope the below link will give more information to you...
**Link :** 
http://raidersec.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html

Comment: Does a web application really have permission to access and decrypt a "password" file? Surely that would constitute a major security hole? I'm really looking for a less "hacky" solution.